# ffmpeg how to process a video to get square pixel effect

Tags: ffmpeg, android, pixels, visual-effects

Using Android, I am trying to add a pixelated effect on a video. I have had a look at the various filters at disposal but there are so many so I don't know which one to use or if there is any which would be suitable...

I have read one could use the frei0r filters but it is not available in the Android Build (WritingMind) which I am using.

Anyone who could help me to achieve a pixelated effect? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic method to do this without a filter is to scale the video down and then rescale it up using the nearest neighbor method.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf scale=iw/4:ih/4,scale=4*iw:4*ih:flags=neighbor out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. Your formula also permits me to increase the size of the pixels.

Comment: @Gyan is this possible to apply this to specific area/part of video?